# Embed PowerApps from a different tenant on a SharePoint page

Tags: canvas, sharepoint, powerapps

I tried to embed a PowerApps application from a different tenant on my SharePoint Online Page using the Embed webpart.

I am passing the app Id and the tenantId in the iframe source.

I also added the current logged-in user as a guest in the other tenant and also I shared the PowerApp with him.

First time the App was loaded successfully, but then after a few refreshes, I got the message: "Sorry, we didn’t find that app."

I am using Chrome. and the issue is sporadic.

Does anyone experienced this issue before? Is this a known issue?

Comment: From the error, it seems it is trying to load the app from the current tenant, even if I passed the tenantId in the iframe source

Comment: Please don't add back your signature. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed